# update password using current password in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

hello guys I am using password controller and I have a method

```
def update
      if @current_user.present? && @current_user.authenticate(:password)
        if @current_user.update(password_param)      
          if @current_user.role.name == "admin"
            redirect_to admin_path, notice: 'password reset in successfully'
            
          else 
            redirect_to show_path, notice: 'password reset in successfully'
          end
        end
      end
```

The problem is when I am using this following code then only I get an error while I am checking @current_user.authenticate(:password) but remaining is correct and is working please help me I am new to rails.
and here is my console error --

```
No template found for PasswordsController#update, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 229ms (ActiveRecord: 1.2ms | Allocations: 10958)
```

Comment: Could you please share the actual error you get? Are you saying that your current_user is not authenticated? Can you post the console output please

Comment: Your problem is most likely related to the value of the password param that you are passing to the authenticate method, If you could please post the console output, then with a few more questions I could probable answer you properly

Comment: my console error -- No template found for PasswordsController#update, rendering head :no_content Completed 204 No Content in 229ms (ActiveRecord: 1.2ms | Allocations: 10958)

Comment: what is your `password_param`? I think `@current_user.authenticate(:password)` is not correct, you should pass password param, ex: `@current_user.authenticate(password_param[:password])`. Where do you define `authenticate` method?. In this case, I think the first if condition is false, so it finds a view to render but there is no view, so it returns no_content.

Comment: @Thanh has that right, you have an issue with the value of `password_param`, but you also have something going wrong with the update action in your controller, you should NEVER be trying to render an update template so you are not handling the error situation correctly at all but you haven't actually posted any useful code yet so it's impossible to help further

Comment: So what is the value of password_param and where are you setting this value? plus you need to handle each of these checks so that they fail gracefully and render the correct template